# SQL Trouble Filtering Down Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently getting results that look like this:

```
Row    | ParentLevel | ChildLevel | 
1      |     1       |     1      |   
2      |     2       |     2      |  
3      |     2       |     3      |
```

I only want a row to appear when parent and child match if there is not a result where they do not match.

In this case, row 1 is fine because it is the only time Parent level 1 appears

Row 2 I would prefer not to appear because row 3 is there, and parent and child do not match in row 3.

Is this possible to set up in a where statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ParentLevel <> t.ChildLevel or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ParentLevel = t.ParentLevel and t2.ParentLevel <> t2.ChildLevel
                 );
```

Comment: `... t.ParentLevel <> t.ChildLevel or...` ?

Comment: So the results I provide above are just a sample set. When you specify select 1, could you clarify what youre specifically selecting?

Comment: @Tyler . . . `not exists` is just checking for the existence of a row.  It doesn't care what the column values are.